Type that has different props based on one of the inner prop type
I have type Item: type Item  = 'itemA' | 'itemB' | 'itemC' | 'itemD';
I have 2 types of items - QuantityBasedItem and BooleanBasedItem:
I have a function that get an item and if the item type is QuantityBasedItem, it also get the quantity:
type MyType<T extends Item> = {
  name: T;
  requirements: T extends QuantityBasedItem ? { units: number } : undefined;
};


const getQuantityBasedItemData = (item: QuantityBasedItem, units: number) => ({item, units});
const getBooleanBasedItemData = (item: BooleanBasedItem) => (item);

function test<T extends Item>(itemData: MyType<T>) {
  if(itemData.requirements?.units){
     getQuantityBasedItemData(itemData.name, itemData.requirements)
  } else {
     getBooleanBasedItemData(itemData.name)
  }
}


now when I use test, I have to send "undefined" for the requirements in case of not quantity-based item.
how can I do it correctly?
test({name: 'itemB', requirements: undefined}); // works OK
test({name: 'itemB'}); // ERROR.

playground

@jcalz, OK, edited

Thanks. So is this approach what you're looking for? Where requirements is optional unless T extends QuantityBasedTime? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

thanks, the problem is that there is no real connection between the 2 props of MyType. If I want to do this:
const getQuantityBasedItemData = (item: QuantityBasedItem, units: number) => ({item, units});
function test<T extends Item>(itemData: MyType<T>) {   if(itemData.requirements?.units){      getQuantityBasedItemData(itemData.name, itemData.requirements)   } }
it won't work

Please put the relevant use cases in the question so it's a [mre], so that we have something to test against.

Oh, you brought back the other q; sorry, I didn't understand that from your comment. It's largely out of scope for this question what goes on inside test(), since generics make things more complicated. I'd say for test(), make it take a discriminated union instead as shown in this playground link. Does this meet your needs? Note how the part with T extends QuantityBasedItem ? { requirements: { units: number } } : { requirements?: undefined } is unchanged, showing that this really is two separate issues. So I'm hoping we can narrow, not widen the scope. Thoughts?

@jcalz thanks, it looks good I think. I will go over it to validate

In the code, if the requirement variable isn't of the QuantityBasedItem type, it's currently being set to undefined. However, under normal circumstances, requirement is expected to hold a value.
My proposed solution is to use the never type in this case. This means that the code would never be able to reach a point where requirement is left undefined.
type Item = 'itemA' | 'itemB' | 'itemC' | 'itemD';
type QuantityBasedItem = 'itemA';
type BooleanBasedItem = Exclude<Item, QuantityBasedItem>;

type MyType<T extends Item> = {
  name: T;
  requirements?: T extends QuantityBasedItem ? { units: number } : never;
};

const getQuantityBasedItemData = (itemName: QuantityBasedItem, units: number) => ({ itemName, units });
const getBooleanBasedItemData = (itemName: BooleanBasedItem) => itemName;

function test<T extends Item>(itemData: MyType<T>) {
  if (itemData.requirements && 'units' in itemData.requirements) {
    getQuantityBasedItemData(itemData.name as QuantityBasedItem, itemData.requirements!.units);
  } else {
    getBooleanBasedItemData(itemData.name as BooleanBasedItem);
  }
}


Obviously I don't know all about your situation, but perhaps you can do something like this:
type BooleanbasedItemData 
    = { name: 'itemA' }
    | { name: 'itemB' };
type QuantityBasedItemData 
    = { name: 'itemC', requirements: { units: number }}
    | { name: 'itemD', requirements: { units: number }};
type ItemData = BooleanbasedItemData | QuantityBasedItemData;

const getBooleanBasedItemData  = (item: 'itemA'|'itemB') => (item);
const getQuantityBasedItemData = (item: 'itemC'|'itemD', units: number) => ({item, units});

function test(itemData: ItemData)
{
    if (itemData.name === 'itemA' || itemData.name === 'itemB') {
        getBooleanBasedItemData(itemData.name);
    }
    else {
        getQuantityBasedItemData(itemData.name, itemData.requirements.units);
    }
}

test({ name: 'itemA' });
test({ name: 'itemB' });
test({ name: 'itemC', requirements: { units: 24 }});
test({ name: 'itemD', requirements: { units: 42 }});

Playground
